# AngularJs: ng-init in radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to display a list of users. I need to use disabled filled inputs with first name, last name, email and a last attribute with radio buttons.
I can easily display the list of name and email but I did not succeed display the good checked button. I tried to use the ng-init directive but this is not working

```
            <div ng-repeat="user in displayUsers" class="text-black form-inline"> 
            <input type="text" value="{{user.nom}}" class="form-control" disabled>
            <input type="text" value="{{user.prenom}}" class="form-control" disabled>
            <input type="text" value="{{user.email}}" class="form-control" disabled>
            <span ng-init="response={{user.response}}">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="" value="1" ng-model="response" disabled>En attente
                <input type="radio" class="radio-inline"name="" value="2" ng-model="response" disabled>Oui
                <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="" value="3" ng-model="response" disabled>Non        
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not what ngInit is for, nor is ngInit necessary. ngModel is in use and it should be in control of whether the radio button is checked or not. Just make sure the model value always has an appropriate value. If the model value is not a simple string, you can use ngValue to specify which model value should result in the radio button being checked.

```
<span>
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="" ng-value="1" ng-model="user.response" disabled>En attente
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline"name="" ng-value="2" ng-model="user.response" disabled>Oui
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" name="" ng-value="3" ng-model="user.response" disabled>Non        
</span>
```

Comment: this is the first thing I tried but it did not work. I guess the model value type might be the problem

Comment: Notice I used `ng-value` not just the `value` attribute. If the value is an integer, it won't work to use `value` because it's always treated as a string.

Comment: Scratch that. For numerics, `value` should still work. You should check the actual value in `user.response`. It may not be what you are expecting.

Comment: Though `ng-value` is still safer, since `3 == '3'` and `3 == '3.0'` but `'3' != '3.0'`. Implicit type conversion can be a gotcha.

Comment: Thanks, it is working well now ! But I have a new issue. My radio buttons are not disabled anymore, and I want to update the values on change in my database. I tried to add ng-change directive on the radios but it is only working on first click, and other items are ignored. Should I use id or something?